# unpack from parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method, unpack

So I have been making an RPG game and run into some troubles with inheritance and unpacking.
I have tried to make a simple version of the problem I am having:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def say_noise(self):
        noise = "I am an animal"
        by_who = "Animal"
        return noise,by_who
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def say_noise(self):
        Animal.say_noise(self)

animal = Animal("man")
doggy = Dog("name")
```

What I want to do is return the same 2 things in the Animal class and the Dog class.
Now when I do say_noise() with my Animal it works fine, as it returns:

```
('I am an animal', 'Animal')
```

However, it does not return anything when I do it with the Dog class, and I tried unpacking them as well (which is what I aim to do in my real code), but when I do this.

```
a,b =doggy.say_noise()
```

it just returns this:

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

How can I return the same thing with the same class method, by only inheriting it from the parent class?

Comment: You need to add a return statement in `Dog.say_noise`, e.g. `return Animal.say_noise(self)`

Comment: Also note that you only need to override parent's methods if you want to change their behaviour - in your case, for example, the `Dog.__init__()` method is just a copy-paste of `Animal.__init__()`, so you should just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not returning anything from `Dog` classes `say_noise` method.
Update your code like this,

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_noise(self):
        noise = "I am an animal"
        by_who = "Animal"
        return noise, by_who


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_noise(self):
        return Animal.say_noise(self)


animal = Animal("man")
doggy = Dog("name")
a, b = doggy.say_noise()
```

Comment: Or better: `return super(Dog, self).say_noise()` (or just `return super().say_noise()` if your using py3 and don't care about py2 compat).

Comment: Of course it is better, I just tried to point out the problem :)

Comment: Thank you, Sazzadur. That makes sense.

Bruno, I am not sure what you mean. what is super?